# C# WPF MainWindow Reference behaves differently to identical alternate reference

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, invalidoperationexception

I have created a minimal WPF example that showcases a confusing issue I discovered in a much more complicated capacity. Essentially, sourcing a reference to the application's Main Window with `Application.Current.MainWindow` from an external thread reliably throws an InvalidOperationException for cross thread object access. *Simply reading the reference*. However! If the given MainWindow has a reference to itself stored in a field, that reference can be read with no issue. It can even be dereferenced, exemplified by accessing one of its properties. Other window fields can also be read and acted upon from the other thread. Why is obtaining the same reference(confirmed with reference equals) a cross thread offense or is not a cross thread offense depending on the way it is read?  `Application.Current` is thread safe, so it isnt to blame. The `MainWindow` property has no documentation elucidating an affinity check on its getter. Why does this happen?

XAML FOR EXPERIMENT:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_TEST.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_TEST"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="Linen">
<Grid>

  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition/>
      <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>  


  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Test Handlers" Click="IReliablyExcept">

    </Button>




</Grid>
</Window>
```

CODE_BEHIND FOR EXPERIMENT

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WPF_TEST
{
 /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly MainWindow mainWindowField;
    private bool someFlag = true;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        mainWindowField = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void IReliablyExcept(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var winRef = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        });
    }

    private async void ButIDont(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var winRef = mainWindowField;
        });
    }

    private async void IDontEither(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (someFlag)
            {
                mainWindowField.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { someFlag = false; });

            }

        });
    }
}
}
```

The Click Event handler can be rewired to try all three variations. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: All properties of UI-objects throws InvalidOperationException if accessed from a Non-UI thread. This behaviour is described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception(v=vs.110).aspx. If a background thread wants to access such a property then it must use the dispatcher. The behaviour you describe is as it should be according to documentation.

Comment: @AedvaldTseh False. I access the same reference, and other mainwindow fields, with no issue as evidenced by the two handlers that do not throw. The two that work may not be safe, but they are functional. The answer below however confirms my suspicions that the property itself is indeed performing an affinity check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply is that way because the `Application.Current.MainWindow` property checks if the calling thread has access.

This is the code of the property from a decompiler, the `this.VerifyAccess();` will reliably throw the exception.

```
public Window MainWindow
{
  get
  {
    this.VerifyAccess();
    return this._mainWindow;
  }
  set
  {
    this.VerifyAccess();
    if (this._mainWindow is RootBrowserWindow || this.BrowserCallbackServices != null && this._mainWindow == null && !(value is RootBrowserWindow))
      throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get("CannotChangeMainWindowInBrowser"));
    if (value == this._mainWindow)
      return;
    this._mainWindow = value;
  }
}
```